# Do unit bivectors square to -1 in vector spaces of any dimension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras

We know that in a 2D vector space (VS) the unit bivector squares to -1. My question is:

Is the geometric product of a unit bivector with itself equal to -1 in any VS, independently of the VS dimension?

Comment: It fails in four dimensions as non-simple bivectors will not have scalar squares.

Comment: This isn't even true in 2D, it's only true when you have Euclidean or anti-Euclidean signature. If $e_1^2 = 1$ and $e_2^2 = -1$ (and these vectors are orthogonal) then $(e_1e_2)^2 = 1$.